# How to create directional drag in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm developing a game in which you race in ships that are hovering above the ground. The problem is that they are really difficult to control because the have no friction other than the drag i set in `Rigidbody` component. Because of that steering is very unresponsive. Setting drag to really high values helps but it works in all directions and thats not what I want. The solution would be making the drag work only sideways so steering is easier, but going forward and backward is normal. Do you know how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

What's your code? Are you adding force by using rigidbody.AddForce? You know that it accepts a second parameter `ForceMode`.

For example:

```
rigidbody.addForce(Vector3.up, ForceMode.VelocityChange)
```

This wil add an instant force, ignoring it's mass. To see other ForceModes, look [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.html) :)

Comment: This is my code: `_rb.AddForce(forwardForce);` so I'm using default `ForceMode.Force`. I don't see any connection between `ForceMode` and my problem. How do you think changing force mode would change sideways drag?

Comment: a bit late, sorry :) But the difference between ForceMode.Force and VelocityChange is that Force applies the force over a long time, which makes it seems liek there is a lot of drag